# Why I receive error, while ext4 primary partition expansion?

Tags: server, partitioning

My ubuntu partition is almost full and I would like to expand it to use all the unallocated capatiy.

First here is the current status:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  352K  395M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  6.8G  546M  93% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Here is the partition table:

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  20G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

When I try to expand it to use the full size I receive the following error:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1 20G
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The containing partition (or device) is only 2094474 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 5242880 blocks.
```

Any idea how I can expand this partition??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize the partition first, then resize the filesystem. Some partition tools like gparted may run the resize2fs in the background for you.  For others, like fdisk, you will have to do it yourself.